# RabbitMQ noAck behaviour

Tags: server, rabbitmq, config

I am preparing rabbitMq setup, what I am confused about is noAck flag because I don't understand exactly the meaning of it. What confuses me is the following:

- If I set noAck: true I assume this means that auto ack is enabled
  which means that rabbit will send a message, but manual ack is not
  necessary which I expected that publishing rate would be the same as
  consumer rate because rabbit won't have any idea when the worker is
  actually finished with processing the message and it will immediately send another message however that is not the case. If consumer is slower than publisher then consumer rate is actually lower and I don't understand why because I thought that messages will be qued in consumers memory and rabbitmq will always send another message even though worker/consumer is not finished with it.

To conclude: why is publisher rate not the same as consumer rate when noAck is set to true

Answer (score 3):

when you set noAck to true it means automatic acknowledgement of messages,
even if the worker is not able to process the message it will be deleted from the queue,

when you set noAck to false that means untill you manually acknowledge that you have successfully processed/acknowledged the message, it will remain in the queue and after certain amount of time it will be requeued and delivered to a different consumer